# Overwriting hydra configuration groups from CLI

Tags: fb-hydra

From the CLI, I am trying to overwrite a group of parameters. The structure of my conf is:

```
conf
├── config.yaml
├── optimizer
│   ├── adamw.yaml
│   ├── adam.yaml
│   ├── default.yaml
│   └── sgd.yaml
├── task
│   ├── default.yaml
│   └── nlp
│       ├── default_seq2seq.yaml
│       ├── summarization.yaml
│       └── text_classification.yaml
```

`task/default.yaml`:

```yaml
# @package task
defaults:
  - _self_
  - /optimizer/adam@cfg.optimizer

_target_: src.core.task.Task
_recursive_: false

cfg:
  prefix_sep: ${training.prefix_sep}
```

`optimizer/default.yaml`:

```yaml
_target_: null
lr: ${training.lr}
weight_decay: 0.001
no_decay:
  - bias
  - LayerNorm.weight
```

`optimizer/adam.yaml`:

```yaml
defaults:
  - default

_target_: torch.optim.Adam
```

This results in the output config:

```yaml
task:
  _target_: src.task.nlp.nli_generation.task.NLIGenerationTask
  _recursive_: false
  cfg:
    prefix_sep: ${training.prefix_sep}
    optimizer:
      _target_: torch.optim.Adam
      lr: ${training.lr}
      weight_decay: 0.001
      no_decay:
      - bias
      - LayerNorm.weight
```

I would like to be able to modify the optimizer via the CLI (say, use sgd), but I am not sure how to achieve this. I tried, but I understand why it fails, this

```
python train.py task.cfg.optimizer=sgd # fails
python train.py task.cfg.optimizer=/optimizer/sgd #fails
```

---

Github discussion [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/discussions/2084).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override default list entries in this form.
See [this](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/defaults_list/).
In particular:

```
CONFIG : A config to use when creating the output config. e.g. db/mysql, db/mysql@backup.
GROUP_DEFAULT : An overridable config. e.g. db: mysql, db@backup: mysql.
```

To be able to override a default list entry, you need to define it as a GROUP_DEFAULT.
In your case, it might look like

```yaml
defaults:
  - _self_
  - /optimizer@cfg.optimizer: adam
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Omry, that works perfectly. I tried to overwrite it from the CLI with `python train.py optimizer=adam` and it did not work but hydra automatically suggested using `python train.py optimizer@task.cfg.optimizer=adam` which worked perfectly! Thanks a lot